# Duplicate value in array and no duplicate value found

Tags: java, arrays

I've a program that if I enter a number the program will trace the duplicate value , and it works fine. It traces the value whether there is any duplicate and it also displays the duplicated value.

What if I enter a number that has no duplicate how do I will inform the users that there is no duplicated value in the array.

Here is the code.

```
case "Search Duplicate Value":
{   
    search = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null , "Search Duplicate Value" , "Search" , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    int parseSearchDuplicate = Integer.parseInt(search);

    for(int i = 0; i <= arrayElements.length ; i++)
    {               
        if(arrayElements[i] == parseSearchDuplicate && i == parseSearchDuplicate)
        {
            equalisStringDuplicate = equalisStringDuplicate + " " + arrayElements[i];                   
        }   
    }           
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , new Label(equalisStringDuplicate + " "),  "Duplicate Value is:" , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);                                
equalisStringDuplicate = "";
break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a boolean value and set it to true if there is match and depending on the value show user a message .try below

```
case "Search Duplicate Value":
        {   
        search = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null , "Search Duplicate Value" , "Search" , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            int parseSearchDuplicate = Integer.parseInt(search);
            boolean isduplicate=false;
            for(int i = 0; i < arrayElements.length ; i++)
            {               
                if(arrayElements[i] == parseSearchDuplicate && i == parseSearchDuplicate)
                {
                    isduplicate=true;
                    equalisStringDuplicate = equalisStringDuplicate + " " + arrayElements[i];                   
                }   
            }           
        }
        If(isduplicate)
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , new Label(equalisStringDuplicate + " "),  "Duplicate Value is:" , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);                                
  else 
      //show no duplicate found
        equalisStringDuplicate = "";
        break;
```

Comment: wait there's something wrong i added a try catch so it will know that the input is IndexOutOfBoundsException and that is actually happening right now whenever i started searching for duplicate value

Comment: Your loop is causing the issue it should run upto i < arrayElements.length. I also updated it in the answer

Comment: what do you mean by my loop causing the issue ?

Comment: Your loop is running upto arrayElements.length() [ i < = arrayElements.length() ] where as it should run upto i < arrayElements.length()

Comment: so there's no problem in the if else statements there ? only the for loop ?

Comment: Yes only in the loop try the change and it will work

Comment: i got it . thanks i compare the equalisStringDuplicate.length == 2 if the condition is true then the No value found is going to prompt,